# A GUI to debug phantomjs script

Tags: phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to build a web crawler. My current crawler is a Python script using selenium, which requires a running Firefox browser. While Selenium is good for debugging scripts (as I can use firebug to inspect the webpage), it cannot be deployed on linux servers without GUI. So I am trying to translate my Python script to phantomjs.

To debug phantomjs scripts, I save the page source html and render a png screenshot to disk, and open it in Firefox to inspect the source page. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, e.g. a plugin for phantomjs, etc.

Comment: Use remote debugging.

Answer (score 5):

This little hack is using a simple technique: It grabs the screen as PhantomJS or CasperJS sees it with captureBase64('png') and then it is POSTing the image into the receiving server which then sends it via socket.io to the browser which displays it is as inline image.

The source code is available on github:

https://github.com/maciejjankowski/flaming-octo-puss

I'm not sure if PhantomJS has it, but CasperJS does (and the latter adds some extra functions to PhantomJS)

and use remote debugging as others suggest

Answer (score 2):

As for most of the JS scripts, it's not so trivial to debug phantomjs script, because there is no IDE/compiler behind this.

First, I higly suggest you to read the [Troubleshooting section](http://phantomjs.org/troubleshooting.html).

As said by torazaburo, your best option is to use Remote Debugging : scripts can be run in a Web Inspector interface-like console : step-in, step-out, break points, local variables... many classic debugger features are available. If you're familliar with Chrome developpers tools, it's pretty the same.

Answer (score 1):

Though not a solution to your Phantomjs troubles,I think Selenium with Python bindings can be used very efficiently as a headless scraper in a Linux environment.

You can use PyVirtualDisplay, a Python wrapper for Xvfb and Xephyr to fake a display.PyVirtualDisplay needs Xvfb as a dependency. On Ubuntu, first install Xvfb:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

then install PyVirtualDisplay from Pypi:

```
pip install pyvirtualdisplay
```

Sample Selenium script in Python in a headless mode with PyVirtualDisplay:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```